# RecyclerView - Mirror it upside down (or: let items stick to bottom)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to use a `RecyclerView` that fills the whole screen. And I want the user to be able to select if the items start at top (as they do by default) or if the start at the bottom (invert the complete logic, order and functions logic of the `RecyclerView`!)

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use this constructor of LinearLayoutManager:

[LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean))

and set `reverseLayout` to `true`.

Comment: seems to do all what i want... i've read the `reverseLayout` parameter but had already forgotten it. Thanks